# Use p5js functions with node, npm minification

Tags: javascript, class, p5.js

I am trying to convert a sketch to use node and bundle a distribution js file. My guess is that some of the function names in p5js must be reserved (to combat this I was going to use a development flag so as not to obfuscate the code at least for testing).

In order to encapsulate the code I am using this method:

```
let sketch = function(p) {
    p.setup = function() {
    ...
}

let myp5 = new p5(sketch);
```

Everything seems to work fine except I cannot call the show function from inside my particle Class (`ReferenceError: noStroke is not defined`)

Here is the full js:

```
let canvasBG;
let particles = [];
let audioFile;
let amplitude;
let vol;
let loaded = false;
let x = 0;
let xoff = 0;
let yoff = 0;

let sketch = function(p) {
    p.setup = function() {
      canvasBG = p.createCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight);
      audioFile = p.loadSound("audio/mom.mp3", p.audioLoaded);
      amplitude = new p5.Amplitude();
      p.rectMode(p.CENTER);
      p.frameRate(30);
      canvasBG.background(255);
    }

    p.audioLoaded = function() {
      audioFile.play();
      audioFile.loop();
      loaded = true;
    }

    p.draw = function() {
      let nx = p.noise(xoff) * p.windowWidth;
      let ny = p.noise(yoff) * p.windowHeight;
      xoff = xoff + 0.01;
      yoff = yoff + 0.02;
      vol = amplitude.getLevel();
      let volumeGate = p.map(vol, 0, 1, p.random(5,12), p.random(80, 550));
      if (loaded) {
        let b = new Particle(nx, ny, volumeGate);
        particles.push(b);
        if (volumeGate > 75) {
            canvasBG.background(p.random(255), p.random(255), p.random(255));
        }
        for (let particle of particles) {
          particle.show();
        }
        if (particles.length >= 10) {
          particles.splice(0, 1);
        }
      } else {
        x+= 0.05;
        p.translate (p.windowWidth - 30, 30);
        p.rotate(x);
        p.noStroke();
        p.rect(0, 0, 2, 40, 0.1);
        p.fill(0, 0, 0, x * 3);
      }
    }
}

class Particle {
  constructor(x, y, r) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
  }
  show() {
    noStroke(); // this is throwing an error
    fill(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(100,255));
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r * 2);
  }
}

let myp5 = new p5(sketch);
```

You can run the current full demo here: https://editor.p5js.org/lharby/sketches/wPF908tqX

I've tried converting the class to a function and passing in arguments, similarly an object and then attaching a function to the object, but can't seem to get anything to work plus I would rather keep the Class as it is.

How is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're super close!

Because you're using p5 in instance mode, p5 functions (such as `noStroke()`, `fill()`, `ellipse()`) won't be available in the global scope, but through the `p` reference.

In your class you simply need to pass `p` as well, similar to how you've already used it with the rest of the code:

```js
class Particle {
  constructor(x, y, r) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
  }
  show(p) {
    p.noStroke();
    p.fill(p.random(0, 255), p.random(0, 255), p.random(0, 255), p.random(100,255));
    p.ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r * 2);
  }
}
```

and in draw pass the reference to p5:

```js
//...
for (let particle of particles) {
          particle.show(p);
        } 
//...
```

Comment: Superb! Thank you so much, felt like I was going around the houses.